# Alfresco Activiti - How to modify process variables?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-share

**How can I modify process variables in Alfresco's workflows?** (embedded Activiti)
I know that they are created when the process is initiated but I'm unable to change them in the Java/JavaScript/process code. (unless I use REST API directly)
I can successfully change local and execution variables ( `execution.setVariable("san_value", "1000");` ) but I am unable to change variables which are shown in the Workflow details page.

Comment: Can you share your code and any errors you are seeing?

Comment: There are no errors. The main variables which are shown in the Workflow details page are just not updating. But it may be because, as @Muralidharan Deenathayalan said, they are fetched from the first task.

Answer (score 2):

For the workflow details, data fetched from start-task . Please how you've added the process variables and how you're accessing it ?

Instead of using process variable, you can add new property(using aspect) in the workflow model and you should be able to access and fetch the variable across all the tasks in the workflow process.

Comment: So you suggest that if I create an Aspect property in my model, its current value will be visible from all tasks and in the result, I would not have to write JavaScript code (TaskListeners) to save the variables after completion of every single task?